# How to prepend number with zero

Tags: java, android

I have the below script running and the following logcat report as at the moment it is not working. Could someone help me get this working and if possible also explain what I am doing wrong.

```
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
         NValue = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
         NValue = String.format("%02d", NValue);
```

Logcat report:

```
05-10 14:02:52.281: E/AndroidRuntime(295): java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d is incompatible with java.lang.String
```

Comment: It would help if you explained what you want this code to do.

Comment: `NValue` should already be a string in the form you want without that last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` for String...

```
String.format("%s", NValue);
```

Like,

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
        String NValue = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        NValue = String.format("%s", NValue);
        System.out.println(NValue);
```

Comment: will this also format a 1 to 01, 2 to 02 etc but 10 is still 10?

Comment: I want to prepend a number until it is 2 characters long with zeros. As 10 is two characters long already it should be left as 10 but anything less should have a zero added.

Comment: @Max - instead of asking, why don't you just try it?

Comment: @Stephen C I'd like to understand instead of trial and error which I have been working at the moment. Thank you Samir

Comment: the "MM" in the SimpleDateFormat ensures two characters

Comment: @SamirMangroliya "MM" are months, "mm" are minutes. I think the OP wanted "mm".